# Spring Cloud Gateway with SSL cannot route to service by name

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I had enable SSL on Spring Cloud Gateway service, and after that routing such as

```
                .route("instruments-ui", r -> r.path("/instruments/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.filter(addCredentials.apply()).preserveHostHeader())
                    .uri("lb://instruments-ui"))
```

ceased normally working. If I change uri to real address such as `http://localhost:8001` routing working right. I use Gateway version 2.0.0.RC1. Can anybody explain how to setup Spring Cloud Gateway + routing with Eureka data + SSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Gateway works with SSL and downstream services works without it, then you need to specify uri as for example `.uri("lb:http://instruments-ui")`. I found it after viewing `LoadBalancerClientFilter` class.